# Como faço para trazer os cpfs iguais de outras tabelas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli

Bom dia, gostaria dessa ajuda.

Tenho uma tabela de "INSCRIÇÃO" onde a mesma possui 2 chaves estrangeiras (CAND_SQ e CANDPL_SQ).
Ambas as chaves estrangeiras possuem um campo CPF.

Gostaria de saber como eu trago os cpfs que são iguais dentro da inscrição.

Ou seja, atualmente tenho uma INSCRIÇÃO onde pode ser feita de duas maneiras diferentes. Inscrição Regular e Inscrição Atraso.
Quando eu for fazer a Inscrição Atraso, caso eu já tenha feito a Inscrição Regular não poderei fazer a Inscrição Atraso.

Comment: Afinal você utiliza o MySQL ou Microsoft SQL Server? Você quer dizer que o conteúdo dos campos CAND_SQ e CANDPL_SQ são unicamente CPF's e quer saber quais se repetem na tabela INSCRIÇÃO?

Comment: É porque eu posso dar o select tanto no MySQL quanto SQL Server, aqui.
Exato, quero saber quais se repetem na tabela INSCRIÇÃO.

Comment: Pesquise pela cláusula HAVING que deve atender a suas necessidades. Como não entendi como está organizada sua tabela não posso chutar um comando SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Para ver quais CPFs se repetem:

```
Select t.cpf
from tabelaComCampoCAND_SQ t
inner join tabelaComCampoCANDPL_SQ t2 on t1.cpf = t2.cpf
```

Mas se a necessidade é só uma validação antes de fazer inscrição atraso, basta vc consultar na tabela de inscrição regular se o CPF já existe:

```
Select 1
from tabelaComCampoCAND_SQ t
WHERE t.cpf = (valorCpf)
```